# Combine multiple tables to act as a single table on BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have several tables with the same schema on BigQuery:

```
dataset.table00
dataset.table01
dataset.table02
...
dataset.table99
```

I want to make a table `dataset.table` that combines all the tables together.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Comma as UNION ALL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#comma_as_union_all) feature of BigQuery

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
  dataset.table00,
  dataset.table01,
  dataset.table02,
  ...
  dataset.table98,
  dataset.table99
```

You can save above as [View](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/querying-data#views) and then use it as

```
SELECT * FROM myView
```

You can use [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions)

```
SELECT *
FROM 
  TABLE_QUERY([project:dataset],
    'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"^table[\d]{2}")')
```